# Finding total number of multi-sets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, self-learning, multisets

I am provided with a multi-set, let's say S with elements as [num1, num2, num3] and these elements are integers (both negative as well as non negative). As this is a multi-set, elements in the multi-set can be present multiple times. I need to choose an element from this multi-set and multiply it with -1. I need to perform this operation m times. I want to find out how many multi-sets are there which can be made from this multi-set. This is home work, so really sorry but I am not able to proceed. I need some help in this. Please give me some hints. I am providing one example.

S = [2, 3, 2]
and m=2
then there are 4 possible multisets

1. [2, 3, 2]
2. [-2, -3, 2]
3. [-2, 3, -2]
4. [2, -3, -2].

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you need a closed formula, or at other answers acceptable?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Whatever you think right.

Comment: You introduced $m$ but never used it. Instead, your example contains an unintroduced variable $K$. Perhaps they two were meant to be the same variable?

Comment: @joriki I updated the question statement

Comment: This is a question from an ongoing contest. Please don't answer it while the contest is ongoing. @vishwasgupta: Please see [our contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774).