# Find possible number of lists that can be formed.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I am new to such problems of number theory. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a list containing n numbers. I can apply the following operation exactly K times.

Pick some element in the array and multiply it by -1

I have to find different number of arrays that can be formed. Eg :-

---

n = 3, k = 1

numbers = 1 2 1

can apply operation to one of three elements. So, I can obtain three different arrays.

ans = 3

---

n = 3 k = 2

numbers = 1 2 1

I can apply to positions (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), I can also apply the operation twice on some element and get the original.

ans = 4

---

**What I tried** :-

nCk is 0 if k>n

I found a pattern :-

combinations = (6C1) + (6C3) + (6C5) + (6C7) // K=7, N=6 - note that K is odd

combinations = (6C0) + (6C2) + (6C4) + (6C6) // K=6, N=6 - note that K is even

Am i missing something in this solution, or is it correct?

Comment: Do not answer this quesiton, it is from a live competition:  https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/CHEFARK

Comment: This is a question from [an ongoing contest](https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/CHEFARK). Please see [our contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774). It's also a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817547).

Comment: This user's [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817950/prime-number-and-stone-game-who-will-win) is also from the active codechef competition.